# Magical code weaving system

Tags: software-recommendations

I'm working on a magic system that works with weaving power. The most commonly used power source is a magical code. I'm trying to base this code off of LaTeX. LaTeX is a math code that is based on TeX. It's useful because it allows complex equations and all sorts of symbols, arrows, etc. I'm wondering: if I'm going to use LaTeX (pronounced: Lay-tech) for my base and want to be able to insert these symbols into my writing by using the code in my actual drafts (not as a base for all of my writing, but as a base for when I want to insert "magical" symbols), what writing platform could I use that accepts both regular writing (fonts, bold, italicize, good for 200-page documents) and the LaTeX math code?

*Edit note: Thank you @Alex for your comment: I hadn't realized this platform accepts LaTeX* 
I experimented and found that three symbols: Alt+= allow LaTeX symbols in an equation in Word. However, I have the problem of fonts. I was interested in the \mathbb font in particular, especially with the effect it gives to letters. Does anyone have a solution to getting a LaTeX font in Word?

Comment: LaTeX? LaTeX is not only used for equations, but also for whole documents. In computer science and probably in other scientific fields, they are widely used for publications

Comment: $ \mathrm \LaTeX $ is a set of $ \mathrm \TeX $ macros, not a "code". It is suitable for typesetting a wide variety of documents, including, for example, novels, reports, scientific papers in biology, chemistry and physics, and not only mathematics. And, as a bonus, you are asking this question *on a platform which accepts $ \mathrm \LaTeX $ notation*, for example $ a \approx b_2 \pm c^2 $. You may also want to consider the readers; most readers cannot read symbols such as $ \nabla $, and many electronic reading platforms cannot show it.

Comment: Pretty sure this is off-topic as it isn't about worldbuilding. Probably should have been asked on Writing.se

Comment: [Blackboard bold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold).

Comment: This question does not look specific to worldbuilding. Also, there are some false assumptions in it (as LATEX is pretty ok to use for documents hundreds pages long). If you can elaborate on the problems you have with long documents, and explain how is this worldbuilding instead of general writing question, please do so. Without it, I don't think it is either objectively answerable or on topic.

Answer (score 0):

MS Word supports both "regular writing" and a huge set of special symbols. I think you can even add more symbols that you find. That probably won't be necessary though, as LaTex should be supported.
If you have trouble here are two links that should help you use LaTex in Word:
[A SuperUser post that should help](https://superuser.com/questions/340650/type-math-formulas-in-microsoft-word-the-latex-way)

[A Microsoft support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/linear-format-equations-using-unicodemath-and-latex-in-word-2e00618d-b1fd-49d8-8cb4-8d17f25754f8)